# Unit test: wait all threads completion before asserting

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, justmock

Inside a test I am creating multiple threads, to test racing conditions, I need the threads start at the same time, so far so good. But when I assert the number of times the method has been executed, if fails because it is not waiting until all the threads have finished.

```
[Test]
public void Test_Racing_Condition()
{
   //Arrange & Act
   var threads = new Thread[20];
   for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
   {
      thread[i] = new Thread(async () => await _memory.GetMemoryAsync());
   }
   foreach (Thread thread in threads)
   {
       thread.Start();
   }
   foreach (var thread in threads)
   {
       thread.Join();
   }

   //Assert
   Mock.Assert(() => _memory.GetMemoryAsync(), Occurs.Exactly(20));
}
```

How can I force the test to wait for all the threads before asserting?

The issue I have is that the assertion is being done, before the threads finish, therefore the test fails.

Comment: This is tagged `async-await` - why not use that? Then you can use `Task.WhenAll`

Comment: Instead of using threads directly, set off 20 tasks, then wait for them all to finish

Comment: ah! I am looking for concurrency, by starting the threads like this, I am able to reproduce racing conditions inside _memory.GetMemomryAsync() method

Comment: What is `_memory`? Can we have a [mcve] please?

Comment: _memory is a class with a method GetMemoryAsync() which returns something, actually it doesn't matter much what, just that consumes CPU

Comment: @DanielV - It does matter when it comes to us testing.

Comment: at least didn't matter for the person that provided the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using **async void** in here: `new Thread(async () => await _memory.GetMemoryAsync())`. as soon as `_memory.GetMemoryAsync()` awaits the first uncompleted await, the method will return and the thread finishes its work.

Try this instead:

```cs
[Test]
public async Task Test_Racing_Condition()
{
   //Arrange & Act
   var tasks = new Task[20];
   for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
   {
      // Use Task.Run to return immediately.
      // Not necessary in production code.
      tasks[i] = Task.Run(_memory.GetMemoryAsync);
   }
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

   //Assert
   Mock.Assert(() => _memory.GetMemoryAsync(), Occurs.Exactly(20));
}
```

If you really need them to start closest to each other as possible:

```cs
[Test]
public async Task Test_Racing_Condition()
{
   //Arrange
   using (var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>())
   {
      var tasks = new Task[20];
      for (int i = 0; i < tasks. Length; i++)
      {
         // Use Task.Run to return immediately.
         // Not necessary in production code.
         tasks[i] = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
               await tcs.Task;
               await _memory.GetMemoryAsync();
            });
      }

      // Act
      tcs.SetResult(null);
   }

   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

   //Assert
   Mock.Assert(() => _memory.GetMemoryAsync(), Occurs.Exactly(20));
}
```

Comment: the first one works just fine, will edit something though:
`tasks[i] = Task.Run(_memory.GetMemoryAsync);`
should be
`tasks[i] = Task.Run(async () => { await _memory.GetMemoryAsync(); });`

Comment: That will just be adding another method and state machine: https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwKwG5nJQDMmM6AwsgN7Lp2YlQAcmAbOgLJwAUAlLfRpJ6IkQDcAhgCd0AFwkBnANYL0AXnQA7AKYB3NgG0YqALr5ho0QDMA9jO4BLTbPQP16VLlfoAPHMUqAHQAMtqaAOayABZeDmBg/BaWggLJovLKCgYOJu5QrIEASgCumtwAIjYA6nZKvOZp9AC+qWlQAJxsgVVRYQCCADYD3Bkq9a0tSeitxJgs+ZwwfK1CjXSSMqOqGjr6+UamDWu29k4ubhqe3n5bIWGRMa7xiWvoq690W9m5GvlFpdxmOg+OoAHyYTqVGpSJR8cZTZKTV4dLo9fpDEYBBTwkRI+itAAOUgcklk2kwcHYCyhtRBanBf3K2gGEgAntw4KgufCmkA===

Comment: upvote my question if you think it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

By Nunit testing, I use DelayedConstraint.  DelayedConstraint delays the application of another constraint until a certain amount of time has passed. In it's simplest form, it replaces use of a Sleep in the code but it also supports polling, which may allow use of a longer maximum time while still keeping the tests as fast as possible.

```
DelayedConstraint constraint = Is.True.After(delayInMilliseconds: 100, pollingInterval: 5);
Assert.That(() => _memory.GetMemoryAsync(), Occurs.Exactly(20), expr: constraint);
```

Comment: I don't want to delay the test because it will impact the overall execution of all of the tests